# Coloring markers in map widget by alarm presence

Tags: thingsboard

I'm using the map widget to show markers for assets and want to color the markers by the presence of alarms for the associated devices, i. e. if there's no (active) alarm for any of the devices associated with the asset, change the color of the marker to green. If there is, change it to red.

I know I can use a javascript function to color the markers, but I don't know how to get the alarm state. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Thingsboard allows you to use builtin options for this.

You can see

- [Dashboard development guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-video-tutorials/#visualization) and
- [ThingsBoard Map widget configuration guide. Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1R75zqQH5c) video, or to be more precise

  - [09:33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1R75zqQH5c&t=573s) — changing color of the marker if the threshold is violated

Comment: Seems like this is a new feature that wasn't available at the time of asking, marking as answer although I'm not using Thingsboard anymore...

Comment: The video shows how to color the markers, just as OP describes they can already do.

But the video does not show how to color based on alarm state (which is what OP asked for).